# On Kivy launcher working fine but APK built fails

Tags: python, kivy

My main.py and other files are working fine when use kivy launcher but when i built .apk with buildozer it is not working as expected .

Below are the things that i have imported in my main.py

```
import re
from kivy.adapters.dictadapter import ListAdapter
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.slider import Slider
from functools import partial
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.network.urlrequest import UrlRequest
import time, threading
from kivy.storage.jsonstore import JsonStore
from kivy.uix.checkbox import CheckBox
```

Do i need to specifically build any of the module. [I guess not] 
Current requirement in buildozer.spec is

```
# (list) Application requirements
requirements = kivy
```

I have used `buildozer -v android debug` command to build apk.

Comment: http://kivy.org/docs/guide/android.html#debugging-your-application-on-the-android-platform

Comment: @inclement i tried that but looking into imports can u say do i need to compile anything else other than kivy for apk building

Answer (score 0):

Add some more requirements such as - re and time and threading such as:

```
# (list) Application requirements
requirements = re, kivy, time, threading
```

list the requirements that you have in your code to get your results
as per kivy adapters is not **supported anymore**.